# Button2 is doing what button1 should be doing

Tags: java, android, button

I'm new to android programming and something weird started happening to my app after i was moving buttons in my layout.
So there is a button (start) that when clicked, launches another activity. Here's the code.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button startbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        startbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {     //STARTBUTTON
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {         //LO QUE HACE EL START BUTTON
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, JugarActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

My problem is that when testing my app, when i click the start button nothing happens, but when i click another button i have in my layout (button4) IT DOES send me to the second activity.
Here's my activity_main.xml in case it is needed.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
    android:minWidth="200dp"
    android:text="@string/Start"
    android:textSize="30sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:maxWidth="200dp"
    android:minHeight="50dp"
    android:minWidth="200dp"
    android:text="@string/Jugarporcontinente"
    android:textSize="30sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minWidth="200dp"
    android:text="@string/Aprende"
    android:textSize="30sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minWidth="200dp"
    android:text="@string/Puntajes"
    android:textSize="30sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button7"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minWidth="200dp"
    android:text="@string/Opciones"
    android:textSize="30sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I don't understand how when clicking a button that doesn't even have code in it, launches code from another button. Any help is welcomed. Thanks.

Comment: I just edited your question to add some better indenting and actually match the braces up.  To keep your code readable - for us and for you - keep matching braces and intends in mind.

Comment: The code provided is for button 1?

Comment: @iWumbo Your question doesn't make sense - this code is in `MainActivity::onCreate`, and `startbutton` is referenced with `findViewById(R.id.button1)`, so yes, it is.

Comment: @JorgeGil Odd - you don't have your `@string` definitions mixed up or anything?

Comment: Try cleaning and rebuilding. It may just be your `R.java` file went wacko.

Comment: The code looks right to me. Does cleaning and rebuilding the project have any effect? Maybe the generated R.java file wasn't updated after your rearranging.

Comment: @hichrist123 and Dave had the solution. I just cleaned it and the problem was resolved.
As i said, im new to programming (started 2 days ago) and i dindn't even knew about this "cleaning" thing. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the question comments, here's what happened:

When the resources are compiled, resource XML files are compiled to binary XML format and resource identifiers are generated in `R.java`. The generated identifiers point to a specific item in the resource binaries. The identifiers are just integers in a sequence, with values given in the order they're declared in the resource XML files.

Most of the time this works all right. When you modify the source XML files, the changes are compiled to both the binary resources and in the `R` class.

However, sometimes the build dependency system does not work correctly. For example, identifiers in `R` are updated but not all binary resource reflect the changed identifiers. When you try to refer to an element by id in code, it actually returns some other element that was specified with that id in binary resources.

In that case you were "lucky" - there was a view by that id in the hierarchy (no null returned and no `NullPointerException`) and it happened to be a `Button` (no `ClassCastException`).

Cleaning the project removes both the compiled resource binaries and generated `R.java` so when recompiled, they are in sync again.